# Polymorphic updating of immutable classes

Tags: scala, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-type

I have been trying to crack my head around this but I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. I can't seem to be able to model it properly in Scala.

Lets say I have a trait `MyTrait` with some immutable classes implementing it.

And it looks something like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
  type Repr <: MyTrait

  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) : Repr

  def substituteAll(
    originals: List[Item],
    replacement: Item
  ) : Repr = {
    originals match {
      case head :: tail => substitute(head).substituteAll(tail, replacement)
      case Nil => this //this complains that this is not of type Repr
    }     
  }
}

trait MyTrait2 { ... }

case class MyClassA(originals: List[Item])
extends MyTrait with MyTrait2 {
  type Repr = MyClassA

  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) : MyClassA = {
    //whatever code that updates the list etc. 

    MyClassA(newOriginals)
  }    
}

case class MyClassB(originals: List[Item])
extends MyTrait with MyTrait2 {
  type Repr = MyClassB

  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) : MyClassB = {
    //whatever code that updates the list etc. 

    MyClassB(newOriginals)
  }    
}

case class CompoundClass(list : List[MyTrait with MyTrait2])
extends MyTrait {
  type Repr = CompoundClass

  def substitute(
    original: Item,
    replacement: Item
  ) : CompoundClass = 
    CompoundClass(list.map(
      myClass => myClass.substitute(original, replacement)
    ))
  )
  //the above complains that it is expecting
  // List[MyTrait with MyTrait2]
  //while in fact it is getting MyTrait2#Repr
}
```

If I were to summarise my problems they would be as follows:

- Updating the immutable classes through a method of the super-trait should return the same type of the implementing class.
- Super-trait needs to be able to return `this` when it makes sense to, rather than return another object. I seem to have a problem with this.
- I need to be able to pass the super-trait to functions without knowing the actual type. Standard polymorphism. So that then the function can call the trait's methods without 
  knowing the actual concrete type.
- I need to be able to use composition to combine classes together into others. (Imagine an expression which is made of sub-expressions). It seems like standard composition, but with the above I am getting those errors with `#Repr`

I had originally tried using a generic type in `MyTrait[T]` but this makes it impossible to pass any concrete class I want. I am trying to use abstract types now and I seem to be facing the same problem at compilation time. Essentially I think there is no difference really now, I am falling in the same pitfall again.

What am I doing wrong? Am I looking at this in the wrong way?

Comment: At a glance, I suspect some of what you want is not possible. But look up "F-Bounded Polymophism" (in Scala) for the pattern that will allow you to achieve your first request: "Updating the immutable classes through a method of the super-trait should return the same type of the implementing class."

Comment: @KevinWright Yes its a refinement of my previous question. I am still having some difficulties with my scenario which is more detailed than the previous one and the previous one does not work.

Comment: @RandallSchulz My first solution was using F-Bounded Polymorphism, thats what I intended with the `MyTrait[T]`. However I was facing a problem that wherever I was expecting `MyTrait` as an argument the compiler started expecting some type for `[T]` and I ended up in a whole mess. KevinWright (in the previous question) suggested that instead I use an abstract type member, which seemed to work well in the small example, however in reality I couldn't even return `this` to functions that returned this type member from the super class, and passing the instance as a parameter started getting `#Repr`

Comment: As Randall says, you're going to need full F-bound with a type param for these use cases.  You can still hide the param by putting another layer in the hierarchy, but it's not the easiest thing to explain from my mobile! If someone else hasn't done so in the meantime, I'll answer in the morning.

Comment: @KevinWright Thanks. If you want to answer on the previous example question it would be fine too. I don't know why I am facing problems with the abstract type member, it seems that in reality it suffers from the same issues. I was expecting that with `type Repr <: MyTrait` and overriding it in the subclasses it would work, but instead I am getting this weird `#Repr` suffix compilation error.

Comment: @KevinWright It seems that the `#Repr` problem is coming specifically from the constructor parameters. When I have a `List[MyTrait]` and try to map it to another list of the same type (to create another immutable object and pass it as a constructor, or even to the `copy` method) I am getting the error that the type of the temporary object being used to traverse the list is `MyTrait#Repr`. And I end up with a type mismatch that the parameter is `List[MyTrait#Repr]` instead of just `List[MyTrait]`. No idea why it is inserting it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here, some of them completely unrelated to polymorphism!

Starting with the `substituteAll` method:

```
trait MyTrait {
  type Repr <: MyTrait

  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) : Repr

  def substituteAll(
    originals: List[Item],
    replacements: List[Item]
  ) : Repr = {
    originals match {
      case head :: tail => substitute(head).substituteAll(tail)
      case Nil => this
    }     
  }
}
```

`substitute` and `substituteAll` both take two arguments, yet you're attempting to call them with one.  This can never work!

You additionally have the issue that the compiler has no evidence that `this` is a `Repr`.  The first problem can be fixed easily enough with zipping the two inputs into a single list of tuples then using an inner function, the second can be fixed by manually providing the evidence:

```
trait MyTrait {
  type Repr <: MyTrait

  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) : Repr

  def substituteAll(
    originals: List[Item],
    replacements: List[Item]
  )(implicit typed: this.type => Repr) : Repr = {
    def loop(pairs: List[(Item, Item)]): Repr = pairs match {
      case (orig, rep) :: tail =>
        substitute(orig, rep)
        loop(tail)
      case Nil => typed(this) //this complains that this is not of type Repr
    }
    loop(originals zip replacements)
  }
}
```

Your next problem is that the `Repr` type param doesn't hold what you want it to hold for the compound type `MyTrait with MyTrait2`.

This isn't a complete type, as the `Repr` param is still abstract.  What you *really* want is the fully-specified type `MyTrait with MyTrait2 { type Repr = MyTrait with MyTrait2 }`

Given that this is somewhat cumbersome, it's easier to introduce another trait to represent it:

```
trait CompoundElem extends MyTrait with MyTrait2 {
  type Repr <: CompoundElem
}
```

You can then use this throughout the rest of the code:

```
case class MyClassA(originals: List[Item]) extends CompoundElem {
  type Repr = MyClassA

  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) : MyClassA = {
    val newOriginals = originals
    MyClassA(newOriginals)
  }
}

case class MyClassB(originals: List[Item]) extends CompoundElem {
  type Repr = MyClassB

  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) : MyClassB = {
    val newOriginals = originals
    MyClassB(newOriginals)
  }
}

case class CompoundClass(list : List[CompoundElem]) extends MyTrait {
  type Repr = CompoundClass

  def substitute(
    original: Item,
    replacement: Item
  ) = CompoundClass(
   list.map( _.substitute(original, replacement) )
  )  
}
```

If you want to keep the element types hanging round a bit longer, this last class could also be written:

```
object MyTrait {
  //type alias helper to view the type member as though it were a param
  //A neat trick, shamelessly borrowed from the shapeless library
  type Aux[R] = MyTrait { type Repr = R }
}

case class CompoundClass[E <: MyTrait.Aux[E]](list : List[E]) extends MyTrait {
  type Repr = CompoundClass[E]

  def substitute(
    original: Item,
    replacement: Item
  ) = CompoundClass(
    list.map( _.substitute(original, replacement) )
  )  
}
```

Written this way, you also don't need the intermediate traits for most scenarios. For example, a `CompoundClass` containing a List of `ClassA`'s will work just fine.

If you want a `List` of assorted `ClassA`'s and `ClassB`'s then you'll still need the intermediates to help the compiler untangle exactly what `Repr` should be, it's not able to calculate that the `Repr` of a `ClassA with ClassB` should also be `ClassA with ClassB`.

and if you don't mind erasing the types of elements entirely, you can do this:

```
case class CompoundClass(list : List[MyTrait]) extends MyTrait {
  type Repr = CompoundClass     
  def substitute(
    original: Item,
    replacement: Item
  ) = CompoundClass(
    list.map( _.substitute(original, replacement) )
  )
}
```

It'll only be a `CompoundClass` of `MyTraits`, and you'll need to use pattern matching when you pull the elements to treat them as `ClassA` or `ClassB` or `MyTrait2`, but you won't need *any* intermediate traits.

---

Finally... For reference, here's the same idea re-implemented using F-Bounds.  Note how the type parameters allow for a `self type`, so you don't need to explicitly define `Repr` in all your subclasses:

```
trait Item {}

trait MyTrait {
  type Repr <: MyTrait

  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) : Repr  
  def substituteAll(originals: List[Item], replacements: List[Item]) : Repr
}

object MyTrait {
  trait Aux[T <: MyTrait.Aux[T]] extends MyTrait { self: T =>
    type Repr = T

    def substituteAll(originals: List[Item], replacements: List[Item]) : T = {
      def loop(pairs: List[(Item, Item)]): Repr = pairs match {
        case (orig, rep) :: tail =>
          substitute(orig, rep)
          loop(tail)
        case Nil => this
      }
      loop(originals zip replacements)
    }
  }
}

trait MyTrait2 { }

case class MyClassA(originals: List[Item]) extends MyTrait.Aux[MyClassA] with MyTrait2 {
  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) = MyClassA(originals)
}

case class MyClassB(originals: List[Item]) extends MyTrait.Aux[MyClassB] with MyTrait2 {
  def substitute(original: Item, replacement: Item) = MyClassB(originals)
}

case class CompoundClass(list : List[MyTrait]) extends MyTrait.Aux[CompoundClass] {
  def substitute(
    original: Item,
    replacement: Item
  ) = CompoundClass(
    list.map( _.substitute(original, replacement) )
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The `substituteAll` problem was just a typo when I was abstracting my code to a simpler example to show here, was too tired to notice the mistake. You got what I meant anyway :). Looking into your answer in more details...

Comment: So, `(implicit typed: this.type => Repr)` worked brilliantly. I didn't know I could specify types that way in there. I am still not quite there with regards to the `Repr` though. Why should `MyTrait` care if the concrete class actually implements other traits? I can't possibly cater for all the possible traits I might implement in the different concrete classes (I have around 10 and they mix and match 4 or 5 other traits which are unrelated to the base one). Why can't I simply say that `Repr` is `MyClassA` and as long as it extends `MyTrait` it doesn't care whether it implements other traits?

Comment: Tweaked the last example + paragraph - it may help you out.

Comment: So, do I have to create an intermediate compound trait for each trait permutation I have? I.e. whenever I create a new class that needs to `extend TraitA with TraitB with TraitC with TraitD` I have to create a new `CompoundABCDTrait`?

Comment: Apart from the above question, for CompoundABCDTrait to be passed to functions where `CompoundABCTrait` or `CompoundABDTrait` or `CompoundBCDTrait` is expected, won't it need to extend all of them?

Comment: Now that I am closing down on finally getting a compilable version, the `implicit type` is back to haunt. I am getting errors like `No implicit view available from _5.type => _5.Repr` too :`(

Comment: Refined things a little, hopefully it'll help :)

Comment: Do you mind explaining a little what's actually happening, honestly totally lost now :(. Does the new `Aux` type solve the `No implicit view available` issue? I am not using that `CompoundClass` because I don't want to risk creating a whole mess again without knowing what I am doing and preferred to create (12!) intermediate classes without generics, pairing together the traits explicitly (its starting to defeat the original scope of avoiding repeated code). I added the companion object of the root trait with the `Aux` type but still have the same error.

Comment: If your hierarchy is that rich, it sounds like you'd be better off with another pattern - type classes for example. Can you give a rough idea of how many classes/traits/methods are involved?

Comment: Well this is for an already defined DSL which has various types of Expressions, so the base trait is `Expression`, which is responsible for some basic methods that take care of terms within an expression (replacing untyped terms with their typed counterparts, and instantiating them, synonymous to the `substituteAll` above), then there are 4 traits which inherit from that, and some other traits which do not extend `Expression` but some concrete  Expressions do, so I had to create a combination trait for each. There are some 20 `Expression` classes, some of which take `List[Expression]`.

Comment: I am finding it really strange why something which seems to have quite a normal hierarchy structure of a few traits extending from each other and a few implementing classes which implement a few other traits is so complex to model. If it was in Java it would have been so straightforward, but adopting an immutable approach seems to screw everything up. Is it my impression that things like the Template Pattern which works perfectly for normal OOP do not quite fit the the functional flavour?

Comment: As used here, `substitute` *is* the template pattern.  Things only get tricky if you want to state that "This is a `CompoundClass` of `MyTrait with MyTrait2`'s".  You're absolutely fine if you stick with the simpler assertion that "This is a `CompoundClass` of `MyTrait`'s".  For something like `Expression`, you probably don't want to track the exact least-upper-bound of elements in a `CompoundClass` anyway, you'd either stick with the template methods or pattern match when enumerating elements.

Comment: Thanks for the latest update! At last I have managed to compile it. I had to remove parameters which used `with Trait2` unfortunately, and ended up with ugly type casts using `asInstanceOf` and pattern matching... so long for compile-time type safety :( ... at least now it works and I can move on. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't use `asInstanceOf`, you should pattern match the values inside a `match` or `collect` block instead.

Comment: Yes I use `match` and `collect` too, especially on lists. But, if for instance I have 2 expressions and I have to check if they are of a certain trait before calling the method of the trait, so it will be `exp1 match { case traitA1 : TraitA => exp2 match { case traitA2 : TraitA => }`, and if the trait's value returns an `Option` it will be two of them again, and I have to match `case _ =>` each time. In reality both are unsafe type-wise the way I see it, which is why I wanted to have the constructor parameters `with TraitA`. I don't know about efficiency, but patterns are more verbose.

Comment: pair the expressions up and match the tuples: `(exp1, exp2) match {case (a: TraitA, b: TraitB) => Some(...) }`